# Unable to launch iOS Simulator using windows visual studio 2017

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on xamarin forms app and trying to debug app on ios simulator using windows visual studio 2017, but when build the app and try to launch app in the simulator it does not show it, only show build success message in the output window, even visual studio is already connected with mac agent and listing out all available simulator on mac machine. So please help me to sort out this issue and let me know what step should i take to get rid it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Try (Command + R) in Xcode to run the app on the simulator.

Comment: thank for your response but simulator already working on mac with xcode

Comment: Have you upgraded the XCode to 9.3?